# React Native Firebase - How to retrieve images from firebase storage and display in Image component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

After getting a ref of an image from firebase.storage().ref('asd'), how do I retrieve the images here and assign to an Image component?

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref('path/to/image.jpg');

<Image
  source={?}
/>
```

Comment: Right now your query is only storing a reference to the path. You're going to want to `.get()` that data. Once you've retrieved the data, you can cycle through and assign their source references accordingly. For more data on `get` check out the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `getDownloadURL()` on the reference to get a URL to the image and then this can be passed as a URI source to the Image component, e.g.:

```js
const ref = firebase.storage().ref('path/to/image.jpg');
const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();

// ... in your render

<Image
  source={{ uri: url }}
/>
```

**Docs:**

v5: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/storage/reference/Reference#getDownloadURL

v6: https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/storage/reference/reference#getDownloadURL

Comment: After upgrading to V6, I couldn't find download url in result object of putFile method. Do you have any idea?

Comment: const url = await ref.getDownloadUrl(); method call here is wrong, should be: const url = await ref.getDownloadURL(); (with capitalization of last three letters)

Comment: "Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!" - https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Comment: Tried to use this answer however I get an error regarding 'await' and how it must be inside an async function?

Answer (score -1):

This might be late but, this worked for me. I had make a separate request to storage, getDownloadURL() is not available on putFile() in rnfirebase v6.

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref("images/name.jpg");
ref.getDownloadURL()
.then(url => {console.log(url)})
.catch(e=>{console.log(e);})
```

Comment: We'll get this fixed - this API should be there on UploadTaskSnapshot